# Nested React list not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, nested-lists

I am trying to recursively render JSON data to nested list using React. Right now I am using simple data object like this:

```
[{"id": "1",
 "name": "Luke"
},
{"id": "2",
 "name": "Jim",
  "childNodes":[{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Lola"
   }]
}]
```

using this class:

```
export default class NestedList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  renderChild = (child) => {
    if (child.childNodes) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {child.myData.map(item => {
            return this.renderChild(item);
          })}
        </ul>
      );
    }
    else if (child.name) {
      return <input type="checkbox"><Child name={child.name}/></input>;
    }
    return null;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <aside>
        <div>
          <h4>Data Sets</h4>
          <ul>
            {this.renderChild(this.props.myData)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}
```

which calls a Child class that creates list element:

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name}=this.props;
    return (
      <li>{name}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

but it doesn't print anything. I have tried removing attribute `childNodes` altogether and tried to print the list but it doesn't work still. I don't understand where I am doing wrong. I would appreciate some help regarding how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map through `myData` first so the rendering process begins:

```
<ul>
  {this.props.myData.map(data => this.renderChild(data))}
</ul>
```

Also, on `childNodes` you need to loop through `child.childNodes`:

```
if (child.childNodes) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {child.childNodes.map(node => this.renderChild(node))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried the first approach and I get this error: `Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

Comment: @user8907896 So go for the second approach :)

Comment: @user8907896 it's actually easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

there were couple of issues here:

1. You passed `myData` to `renderChild` which doesn't hold `childNodes`
   property nor `name` property. Hence none of the conditions were met
   (null was returned).
   So maybe you should loop through `myData` and
   pass each member of the array to `renderChild`.
2. Even if we will pass a valid "child" to the `renderChild` method,
   inside this condition:

   ```
   if (child.childNodes) {
   ```

   Again you are using a wrong property:

   ```
   <ul>
     {child.myData.map(item => {
     return this.renderChild(item);
     })}
   </ul>
   ```

   this should be:

   ```
   {child.childNodes.map(item => {...
   ```
3. Last thing, You can't nest child elements inside an `input` element.
   so change the layout, maybe like this? :

   ```
     <input type="checkbox"/>
     <Child name={child.name} />
   ```

Here is a running example with your code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Luke"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Jim",
    childNodes: [
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Lola"
      }
    ]
  }
];

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  renderChild = child => {
    if (child.childNodes) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {child.childNodes.map(item => {
            return this.renderChild(item);
          })}
        </ul>
      );
    } else if (child.name) {
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox"/>
          <Child name={child.name} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <aside>
        <div>
          <h4>Data Sets</h4>
          <ul>{this.props.myData.map(item => this.renderChild(item))}</ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { name } = this.props;
    return <li>{name}</li>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NestedList myData={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```